# JavaScript string.includes() method at specific index, without modifying original string?

Tags: javascript, string

I am wondering if there's a way to use the `str.includes()` function in JavaScript, but check at a certain index of the string, without changing the original string. For example:

```js
var str = "this is a test";
str.includes("test");     //returns true
str.includes("test", 0)   //returns false, as "test" is not at position 0
str.includes("test", 10)  //returns true, as "test" is at position 10 in the string
```

I've been trying to find a way to do this, but haven't been able to figure it out. Could somebody please help me?

Comment: The code you posted should work, what's the problem you're running into?

Comment: Why don't you do `str.indexOf("test") === 0` or `=== 10`?

Comment: It returns `true` regardless of what number I put as the second argument.

Comment: Yeah the position parameter only indicates where to start searching, not whether the item only exists at that index. `indexOf()`, `lastIndexOf()`, or `matchAll()` may be more helpful for whatever your use case is.

Comment: How about `str.slice(10).startsWith('test')`?

Comment: @arieljuod What if there's multiple instances in the string? Then it would only return `true` if the first instance is there, not any following ones.

Comment: @CherryDT The way I'm implementing this into my script requires me not to modify the original string, unfortunately.

Comment: This doesn't modify the string. (If it's a large string, oezingle's answer is better, even if the code is longer, because it creates only a copy of the part that needs comparison, not of everything starting at that index which my suggestion does for simplicity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) has something close to this functionality, as argument 2 is taken as the **start** position for searching.

If you want to search at, not after, a specific index, you can write a function that takes the string, creates a slice of it, and checks if that slice matches

```
function substring_at(string, substring, position) {
  let slice = string.slice(position, position + substring.length)
  
  // Triple equals removes type coercion support, and is slightly faster
  return slice === substring
}
```

I've tested it with your examples and all seems well.

Comment: No, "The slice() method does not change the original string." - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp